# cannot make full functionality of lock slider with the use of seek bar

Tags: android

converted android seek bar to lock slider but how to disable progress change when user single tap on the Seekbar in Android

Answer (score 0):

simply read the event type and if the event is of type drag move the slider

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    int x = (int)event.getX(); // get the X position of the drag event
    int y = (int)event.getY(); // get the Y position of the drag event

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){       
        slider.x = ... //move slider
    }
    ...

    return true;    
}
```

hope this helps ! :)